# Keybindings in emacs for shortcuts

Tags: emacs

In vim, it is easy to define keybindings of the form

imap \pd \partial

which allows one to define shortcuts for commonly used commands. Is there a way to do the same in one's .emacs file? I am only aware of how to do this for editor commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's explained in [this section](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-Rebinding.html#Init-Rebinding) of the manual.
In the simplest form, a key sequence is globally associated with a function:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-z") 'shell)
```

binds `Control-Z` to the shell function.

If that doesn't fully answer your question, please elaborate.  You may want to say what that vim binding does, and explain what you mean by "editor command."

EDIT: To insert text, you use the `insert` function.  You can wrap this in a lambda:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-z") (lambda ()
                  (interactive)
                  (insert "text to insert")))
```

You may also want to look at [Abbrevs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Abbrevs.html#Abbrevs).

Comment: Yes, but I don't know what the shell command in emacs for "insert this block of text" is. The vim binding will automatically expand "\pd" to "\partial."

Comment: Anyone else reading the answer above - **do** check out abbrevs. They are awesome. And easy to use.